# PostgreSQL: How to find the last descendant in a linear "ancestor-descendant" relationship

Tags: postgresql, ancestor

I have the following DB structure:

```
RELATIONSHIP_TABLE
- id << primary key
- id_ancestor << foreign key to the same table
- id_entry << foreign key to "ENTRY_TABLE"

ENTRY_TABLE
- id
- name
...
```

The hierarchy in table "`RELATIONSHIP_TABLE`" is linear. That means a record can be at most ancestor of one other record. Examples:

```
1. record1
2. record2 <- record3 <- record4
3. record5 <- record7 <- record9 <- record12
```

Every record within a particular hierarchy has the same "`id_entry`". Now, I would like to find the last descendant with a specific "`id_entry`". The result of the examples below would be:

```
1. record1
2. record4
3. record12
```

Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks in advance :)

QStormDS

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM relationship_table rt
WHERE rt.id_entry = 42
AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM relationship_table nx
   WHERE nx.id_entry = 42      -- you can possibly omit this clause  
   AND nx.id_ancestor = rt.id  -- No children poining to rt ...
   )
 ;
```

Comment: Hi again, this query is working well. However, I have got an additional requirement and I don't know how to solve this with this query.

Requirement: The last descendant where a flag (column of relationship_table) is set to true

Example:
record5(flag = false) <- record7(flag = true) <- record9(flag = false) <- record12(flag = false)
result should be record7

Comment: I don't understand. I suggest you start a new question, with all the old and new requirements.