# How to find the last descendant (that matches other criteria) in a linear “ancestor-descendant” relationship

Tags: postgresql, hierarchical-data, ancestor

This question is based on the following question, but with an additional requirement: [PostgreSQL: How to find the last descendant in a linear "ancestor-descendant" relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792296/postgresql-how-to-find-the-last-descendant-in-a-linear-ancestor-descendant-re)

Basically, what I need is a Postgre-SQL statement that finds the last descendant in a linear “ancestor-descendant” relationship that matches additional criteria.

Example:

Here the content of table "RELATIONSHIP_TABLE":

```
id | id_ancestor | id_entry | bool_flag
---------------------------------------
1  | null        | a        | false
2  | 1           | a        | false
3  | 2           | a        | true
4  | 3           | a        | false
5  | null        | b        | true
6  | null        | c        | false
7  | 6           | c        | false
```

Every record within a particular hierarchy has the same "id_entry"
There are 3 different “ancestor-descendant” relationships in this example:

```
1.    1 <- 2 <- 3 <- 4
2.    5
3.    6 <- 7
```

Question [PostgreSQL: How to find the last descendant in a linear "ancestor-descendant" relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792296/postgresql-how-to-find-the-last-descendant-in-a-linear-ancestor-descendant-re) shows how to find the last record of each relationship. In the example above:

```
1.    4
2.    5
3.    7
```

So, what I need this time is the last descendant by "id_entry" whose "bool_flag" is set to true. In the example above:

```
1.    3
2.    5
3.    <empty result>
```

Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks in advance :)

QStormDS

Comment: I your example the anchestor relations are sorted (like ancestors always have smaller ids then descandants). Is that always in your scenario the case?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the answer to the first question is wrong; I can't see how it could possibly handle chains of ancestry.

Comment: Should not the record with {id=5 , id_entry=b,bool_flag=True} be also in the intended output ?

Comment: Please refrain from using the title to tag your question. Use the tagging system instead.

Comment: So ... is `id_entry` supposed to be the same for all entries within the same chain? Is this enforced by a foreign key, so you can rely on it? If so, my query can be simplified.

Comment: @Angelo Neuschitzer: Its only sorted in the example in order to make it easier to read.

Comment: @wildplasser: You are right. Fixed.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid: OK, I will do it.

Comment: @Craig Ringer: "id_entry" is the same within one chain. Its an foreign key. Is just simplified it for the example.

Answer (score 3):

Graphs, trees, chains, etc represented as *edge lists* are usually good uses for recursive common table expressions - i.e. `WITH RECURSIVE` queries.

Something like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE walk(id, id_ancestor, id_entry, bool_flag, id_root, generation) AS (
  SELECT id, id_ancestor, id_entry, bool_flag, id, 0 
  FROM RELATIONSHIP_TABLE 
  WHERE id_ancestor IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT x.id, x.id_ancestor, x.id_entry, x.bool_flag, walk.id_root, walk.generation + 1
  FROM RELATIONSHIP_TABLE x INNER JOIN walk ON x.id_ancestor = walk.id
)
SELECT 
  id_entry, id_root, id
FROM (
  SELECT 
    id, id_entry, bool_flag, id_root, generation,
    max(CASE WHEN bool_flag THEN generation END ) OVER w as max_enabled_generation
  FROM walk
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id_root ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
) x
WHERE generation = max_enabled_generation;
```

... though it feels like there really should be a better way to do this than tracking how many generations we've walked down each path.

If `id_entry` is common for all members of a tree, you can avoid needing to track `id_root`. You should create a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(id_entry, id)` and a foreign key constraint on `FOREIGN KEY (id_entry, id_ancestor) REFERENCES (id_entry, id)` to make sure that the ordering is consistent, then use:

```
WITH RECURSIVE walk(id, id_ancestor, id_entry, bool_flag, generation) AS (
  SELECT id, id_ancestor, id_entry, bool_flag, 0
  FROM RELATIONSHIP_TABLE
  WHERE id_ancestor IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT x.id, x.id_ancestor, x.id_entry, x.bool_flag, walk.generation + 1
  FROM RELATIONSHIP_TABLE x INNER JOIN walk ON x.id_ancestor = walk.id
)
SELECT
  id_entry, id
FROM (
  SELECT
    id, id_entry, bool_flag, generation,
    max(CASE WHEN bool_flag THEN generation END ) OVER w as max_enabled_generation
  FROM walk
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id_entry ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
) x
WHERE generation = max_enabled_generation;
```

Since this gives you a table of final descendents matched up with root parents, you can just filter with a regular `WHERE` clause now, just append `AND bool_flag`. If you instead want to exclude chains that have `bool_flag` set to false at *any* point along the way, you can add `WHERE bool_value` in the `RECURSIVE` query's join.

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/92a64/3

Comment: Hi get an error when i execute the query (BTW: I am using postgre 8.4.1): ERROR:  frame start at CURRENT ROW is not implemented
LINE 16:   WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id_root ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW...

Comment: @QStormDS Well, that's what you get for not specifying your version in questions I'm afraid: if you don't say otherwise I'll assume you're on the current version and test accordingly. `ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` isn't actually necessary in the final version of the query (I was using `row_number` in a way that needed it before) ... so you might be OK with just deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH RECURSIVE tail AS (
    SELECT id AS opa
            , id, bool_flag FROM boolshit
    WHERE bool_flag = True
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.opa AS opa
    , b.id, b.bool_flag FROM boolshit b
    JOIN tail t ON b.id_ancestor = t.id
    )
SELECT *
FROM boolshit bs
WHERE bs.bool_flag = True
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM tail t
    WHERE t.opa = bs.id
    AND t.id <> bs.id
    AND t.bool_flag = True
    );
```

Explanation: select all records that have the bool_flag set,
EXCEPT those that have offspring (direct or indirect) that have the bool_flag set, too. This effectively picks the last record of the chain that has the flag set.

Comment: @QStormDS If you're using a solution you should generally accept it as the most correct answer with the green tick. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work